# Implementing 2 different google custom search boxes on same page

Tags: google-custom-search

I have implemented two different Google custom search boxes (GCSE) on my website http://theoff.info/: (1) gcse for website search (in header) (2) gcse for hotels in ladakh (after main slideshow in a column Search Hotels in Ladakh). But both deliver search results of the second gcse because both search box codes assign unique gcse codes to same variable cx.

I changed the cx and gcse to cx1 and cx2 and gcse1 and gcse2 in widget area of my website as suggested at [How to have multiple Google Custom Search field on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512776/how-to-have-multiple-google-custom-search-field-on-the-same-page). The search boxes disappeared from page http://theoff.info/. So I have reset cx and gcse. I am getting same results from both gcse boxes.

Could you tell me how to rename var cx and gcse in the code?
Or
any other easier method to force the two different engines to produce two different kinds of results?

Thanks