# Two different google cse do not work on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make two different results from Google custom search in a single page.

my code:

```
<div id="1">
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'cse code 1';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only gname="one"></gcse:searchresults-only>
</div>


<div id="2">
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'cse code 2';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only gname="two"></gcse:searchresults-only>
</div>
```

When both codes are added, no results are displayed. But if one of them exists, the result will be displayed. But I need to display the result of both in two different blocks

Comment: change `var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];` to `var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1];` in second code and try

Comment: Changed, But the result will not be displayed again

Comment: try this one:-[How to have multiple Google Custom Search field on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512776/how-to-have-multiple-google-custom-search-field-on-the-same-page)

Comment: That article works for cse V1. But it does not work for the cse V2!