# Multiple GCSE's on page at one time.

Tags: google-custom-search

Using the new GCSE code like so:

```
                    // google custom search engine for the whole site
                (function() {
                    var cx = '*****************';
                    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                    gcse.async = true;
                    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                            '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx + '&gname=sitesearch';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                })();
```

and the element like so:

```
            <gcse:searchbox gname="sitesearch"></gcse:searchbox>
            <gcse:searchresults gname="sitesearch"></gcse:searchresults>
```

How do I go about including a second gcse tag on page and Assiging it a new CX:
I've tried passing the gname for each to the url like so :

```
'//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx + '&gname=sitesearch';
```

but to no avail... 
I've read the documentation where it says;

> (Optional) A name for the CSE element object. A name is used to retrieve an associated component by name, or to pair a searchbox component with a searchresults component. If not supplied, Custom Search will automatically generate a gname, based on the order of components on the webpage. For example, the first unnamed searchbox-only has the gname "searchbox-only0" and the second has the gname "seachbox-only1", and so on. Note that the automatically generated gname for a component in two-column layout will be two-column. The following example uses the gname storesearch to link a searchbox component with a searchresults component:
>   which makes it easy to assign the searchbox to the search results I just can't seem to attach the cx code to the actual tag.

I've read this: 
[Multiple Google CSE (Custom Search Engine) Boxes on Same Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589725/multiple-google-cse-custom-search-engine-boxes-on-same-page)
but that refers to an older version of GCSE 
and this one where the accepted answer is use an iframe: 
[How to have multiple Google Custom Search field on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512776/how-to-have-multiple-google-custom-search-field-on-the-same-page)

Using an iframe just seems cludgy and not the right way to do it... 
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Custom Search Element v1 it can be done relatively easy:

```
<script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('search', '1', {style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  new google.search.CustomSearchControl('CSE_USER_ID:CDE_ID1').draw('cse');
  new google.search.CustomSearchControl('CSE_USER_ID:CDE_ID2').draw('cse2');
});
</script>

<div id='cse' style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>

<div id='cse2' style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
```

Demo: Multiple Google CSE on the same page
http://box.galeksic.com/cse.multiple-on-same-page/

JavaScript API Reference (v1)
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference

I've tried with v2, but wasn't very successful.

Comment: yeah that doesn't work does it :D .... 
So Iframe is the only way to go then it seems...

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this same problem and came across [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/customsearch/CykID1VAUiM/npPCTGLDaUAJ) on the google product forums.

Basically, the answer is to use a single CSE and differentiate what you're searching using [refinements](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631064?hl=en), which allow you to scope the searched URLs using labels in your CSE settings.

*Note: make sure to set the refinement to 'search only sites with this label' assuming that's what you want.*

Then, in your HTML code, specify the default refinement you want to use for each results box like so:

```
<script>
  (function() {
  var cx = 'your-cse-id-here';
  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
  gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>

<gcse:searchresults-only defaultToRefinement="refinement-tag-1"></gcse:searchresults-only>

<gcse:searchresults-only defaultToRefinement="refinement-tag-2"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

For my use, I wanted to not display the default refinement tabs (and have the two result boxes look like they were independent) so I used CSS to hide the 'gsc-tabsArea' elements.

[More info on v2 CSE API and refinements...](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#customizing)

Here's a working codepen: http://codepen.io/mikedaul/pen/xqxYOO?q=flowers

Hope this helps!