# Two custom searches in same page disables search predictions

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

While using different styles for larger displays and mobiles, I was forced to insert **two google custom search boxes in same page**. The search still works perfectly but the issue is that **search predictions are no longer available** after inserting the second search box.

```
(function() {
    var cx = '*****************:**********';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

The same code is using twice in the same page(especially **repeated id usage**) which causes the conflict I think.  Already referred similar posts '[How to have multiple Google Custom Search field on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512776/how-to-have-multiple-google-custom-search-field-on-the-same-page)' and '[Multiple GCSE's on page at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087411/multiple-gcses-on-page-at-one-time)', but those are not solutions for the situation which I'm facing. **How to enable both search boxes in same page work in a similar manner without causing conflict?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently experimenting with this. Getting 2 cse's with a different cx on the same page isn't that hard, but can't get the suggestions working. The v2 control api method description isn't very clear.

But with a single cx you can just do this:

html:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<br/>
<div id="second"></div>
```

js:

```
var renderSearchElement = function() {
    google.search.cse.element.render({
        div: "first",
        tag: 'search'
    });
    google.search.cse.element.render({
        div: "second",
        tag: 'search'
    });
};

var myCallback = function() {
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
        renderSearchElement();
    } else {
        google.setOnLoadCallback(renderSearchElement, true);
    }
};

window.__gcse = {
    parsetags: 'explicit',
    callback: myCallback
};

var loadElements = function() {
    var cx = '*****************:**********';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
}

loadElements();
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/501g48d4/

CSE v2 control API and render params: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element